# Save Excel Report to Client selected Directory in java

Tags: java, servlets

Using Apache POI , I'm able to download the file as report. But it is saving in D directory. Since, I hardcoded D directory in my code . 
Below snippet is to store the report.

```
public static synchronized String writeToExcelReportGeneration(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
        try{
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\excelFormat.xslx"));
                    workBook.write(out);
                    out.close();

                }
    }
```

Here is my AJAX call.

```
    $.ajax({
     url : "${path}/user/customer/scriptTimeCompareReportGenerate",
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "text",
        data : {export_type:exp_Drp_Id,
        script_id:scriptChkId,
        created_timestamp:timeStamp},
        success : function(response){
            if (response.length>0){
                if (response == "Excel"){
                    alert("Reports are exported to excel successfully");
                } else if (response == "PDF"){
                    alert("Reports are exported to PDF successfully");
                }
                } else 
                    alert("Failed to Export");
                }
                });
```

My question is, before the report save to D directory, It has to prompt for where the file should save. Just like enctype="multipart/form-data".. Need your valuable suggestions Please

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like your client sever architecture is not proper. Because you are using same machine as client and server that's why you are feeling it is getting downloaded but actually your code is generating the file in server's "D-Drive". To download the file at client side what you need to do is:
1) Generate the file at server side.
2) Than you can just give a link to that file, so from client side file can be downloaded.

Comment: Shruthi, can you tell me, you want to generate the file before ajax call or after ajax call..???

Comment: see the other comment

Answer (score 0):

At client side you can't generate the file. So what you need to do is, after ajax call, call writeToExcelReportGeneration() method which will generate the excel file. Now with the response attach the file and send it at client side.

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
     response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=file.xlsx");
FileInputStream in = 
            new FileInputStream(new File("file.xlsx"));
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
while(in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1){
            out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
        }
        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
```

OR
serve the folder as public and on success of ajax perform another ajax call:

```
success : function(response){
 $.ajax({
     url : "/path/to/file.xlsx",
});
}
```

Comment: Hi, Tried. But I'm getting a response as a character string . Please if u have any samples( Spring MVC ) . Let me know @Shubhasmit

Comment: Try the 2nd approach, it'll be easier.